# How do I set the global font in MDriven Turnkey

Tags: mdriven

I can find the Views/EXT_Overidepages and the set Index.cshtml. But how do I reach the __Layout.cshtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load your font using @font-face in CSS.

Add it to the tkuser.css file. Read about that here https://wiki.mdriven.net/index.php/Tkusercss